# How To Add Input Object On Top (Overlapping) MapActivity

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android development and have been trying to create a test app with map activity.

I was able bring Action bar along with map on emulator as well as on my phone. But I am struggling to add a input box on map activity.

I am able to add those input box on other activities but not on map.

I need it it like this:

[image: Map]

Here is the Layout code:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="in.co.abc.app.abc.MapsActivityHome" />
```

Comment: can you add the full layout code so that it could be edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your map fragment and EditText inside a Relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="in.co.abc.app.abc.MapsActivityHome">

<fragment 
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="in.co.abc.app.abc.MapsActivityHome" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Position your EditText as per your wish, for now, I just set it as a center in the parent.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: It would be foolish to ask (still trying to get hold of AS development), do I add the above code to my Layout xml file in addition to what I have mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 2):

Put your editText alongside your map fragment inside a RelativeLayout, (or FrameLayout):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="in.co.abc.app.abc.MapsActivityHome" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:padding="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You could also add fragment programmatically with a fragment transactions, which I believe is a more preferred way of working with fragments.